# Best translation of "just wanted to"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

In English, I often use "just wanted to" to soften the force of a question or statement:

- I just wanted to ask if it was okay with you.
- I just wanted to make sure you were coming to the meeting tomorrow.
- I just wanted to see what you thought about this.

What is the most natural way in Spanish to convey this sense? Does the literal translation (*Quería preguntarte...*) make sense, or is it better to use another option (*quisiera*, *me gustaría*, etc.)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say

> Solo/solamente quería...

So, considering your sentence I could say something like this (the translations might change, the main point is the expression you were looking for):

> - Solo quería preguntarte si estabas de acuerdo.
> - Solamente quería asegurarme de que ibas a venir a la reunión mañana.
> - Solo quería saber qué pensabas de esto.

Comment: I would use *sólo/solamente* too.

Comment: Kevin, I didn't know that rule for "solo"... @Auron Do you confirm that? (Check the Edit comment left by Kevin) and the post by Paloma on the site onehourtranslation, [here](http://forum.onehourtranslation.com/topic/spanish-solo-vs-solo).

Comment: I didn't know it either! The rule has changed since I studied it when I was a child, but the DPD is clear (http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=tilde2#323): *solo* (adverb) needs accent when there is some possible ambiguity, which is not the case here. However, as this seems to be a recent change to the rules, you will probably find *sólo* with accent even in contexts when there is no possible confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que lo apropiado es usar las formas "quisiera", "me gustaría" o incluso "quería":

- I just wanted to ask if it was okay with you.

> Me gustaría saber si le parece bien.
>
> Quisiera saber si le parece bien.
>
> Quería saber si está de acuerdo.

- I just wanted to make sure you were coming to the meeting tomorrow.

> Quería asegurarme de que ibas a asistir a la reunión mañana.

- I just wanted to see what you thought about this.

> Me gustaría saber qué piensa usted.
>
> Quisiera saber su opinión.
>
> Quería saber qué piensa usted.

Comment: *Quisiera* sounds really polite and gives a lot of softening. *Me gustaría* is a little less so and less formal sounding. One of those is probably what you want.

Comment: I disagree with Brian's rejection of *quería*.  It's very nicely equivalent, functionally, to the original expression.